# PyQt save objects to file

Tags: python, file, object, io, pyqt4

I would like to savec PyQt objects (ie: QTreeWidgetItem or others) to files.
I tried it with pickle but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/enjoysmath/pyqt_pickle

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize many of them using the facilities provided by Qt for serialization, namely [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) ([also in PyQt docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdatastream.html)).

Comment: thanks for your answer.  
i m gonna try to figure how to use it.

Comment: ok, i m lost :/  
I can t figure out how to convert an object into a QByteArray

Comment: Why should you? Qt already provides << operators to serialize its types to QDataStream...